Sumifs across multi-column spill range, Top x & Group remaining together using spill formulas
All, my goal is to have a summary output of spill formulas that generates the top x of rows, but the last row grouping all the other rows so the totals will tie to the data source. (The first image shows generally how it's working, the second shows how I'd like it to be. Markdown table included for testing.) If there's a better way to phrase the title, let me know and I'll adjust.
The source table is generated by spill formulas against a pivot table. I do this so I am able to get the total I'm meant to tie to before I start combining fields, which pivot tables don't have a clean solution for (to group the top x fields, you need to select them manually, but I need this to be dynamic).
In the image, the first table (on the left) is all spill formulas. The Dept numbers across the top and ID's down the side are generated, as are the values.
The second table is attempting to take the top 5, and then sum everything after the top 5 into the "Others"; however as you can see this is taking data for the ID 6, instead of everything greater than 6. I tried the formula a few ways but couldn't get it to sum all of the columns at once while also doing this. One solution requiring I copy the formula for additional columns or removing them when there's less as this won't be static.
Constraints: The first table is generated from spill formulas, the numbers of rows and columns is not static, so the second table needs to take that into account. For the example, I used Sequence() for the headers and rows, and a random formula for the values to have some data.
The formula works for everything but the "Others" row:
=MAKEARRAY( ROWS(I2#), COLUMNS(K1#), LAMBDA(r,c,SUM(C2#*--(A2#=INDEX(I2#,r))*--(C1#=INDEX(K1#,1,c)) )))
I tried to modify the formula in K2 to below but it resulted in #N/A:
=MAKEARRAY( ROWS(I2#), COLUMNS(K1#), LAMBDA(r,c,SUM(C2#*--IF(I2#>5,(A2#>=INDEX(I2#,r)),(A2#=INDEX(I2#,r)))*--(C1#=INDEX(K1#,1,c)) )))

This is the desired output:

(Markdown for testing)



ID/Dept
Name
1
2
3
4
5




1
Tom
2.00
3.25
4.50
5.75
7.00


2
Joe
2.75
4.00
5.25
6.50
7.75


3
Christine
3.50
4.75
6.00
7.25
8.50


4
Mark
4.25
5.50
6.75
8.00
9.25


5
Ben
5.00
6.25
7.50
8.75
10.00


6
Jane
5.75
7.00
8.25
9.50
10.75


7
Kerry
6.50
7.75
9.00
10.25
11.50


8
Jack
7.25
8.50
9.75
11.00
12.25


9
Rose
8.00
9.25
10.50
11.75
13.00


10
Michelle
8.75
10.00
11.25
12.50
13.75


11
Michael
9.50
10.75
12.00
13.25
14.50


12
Paul
10.25
11.50
12.75
14.00
15.25


13
Jose
11.00
12.25
13.50
14.75
16.00


14
Shonda
11.75
13.00
14.25
15.50
16.75


15
Erik
12.50
13.75
15.00
16.25
17.50



Here's a question that helped me create the first formula

Will this not work ? =VSTACK(TAKE(A2:G16,5), HSTACK(6, "Others", BYCOL(DROP(A2:G16,5,2), LAMBDA(x,SUM(x))))) or without LAMBDA() --> =VSTACK(TAKE(A2:G16,5), HSTACK(6, "Others", MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(A2:G16)-5)^0,DROP(A2:G16,5,2))))

@MayukhBhattacharya the first table is not a single continuous array, so the first section of Take(A2:G16) would need to be constantly re-referenced whenever any change is made to the sheet.

Use a table (Insert > table). Then you can reference a named column - regardless of the size of the table.

The can be made more shorter with ETA LAMBDA() --> =VSTACK(TAKE(A2:G16,5), HSTACK(6, "Others", BYCOL(DROP(A2:G16,5,2), SUM)))

@Ike you can't create a table on a spill range.

@MayukhBhattacharya perhaps I was unclear, the problem isn't the formula is long to type, the problem is that every time the source of data changes the first table in the image will expand, meaning on my output table I would have to keep changing the references. The solution requires this be dynamic.

Sir, no that is what @Ike ma'am has said, she has asked you to convert your source range into  Structured References aka Tables and use the same references in the formulas

@MayukhBhattacharya That is not an option. The source of data is a pivot table connected to an OLAP connection, I cannot query this into a raw table, and we cannot do a table format on the spill output.

Sir, no why will you convert your output to Tables, Dynamic array formula dont work with Tables, and if the source is an OLAP connection then why not make the transformation to import a table and instead of using the connection for Pivot table.

I won't convert my output to tables, which is why I keep saying spills don't work with tables. The source is OLAP Data Cube, that as I mentioned I cannot query this into a raw data due to the way it's structured behind the scenes. Otherwise I'd have pulled the data how i needed to get the easiest, most effective solution.

Sir, misunderstanding, I am not asking you to convert the formula output into a Tables I was asking you to import your OLAP connected data as a Table instead of using it as a connection, however try the last formula, which i have used LET() function with lastrow based on column. should that work for you sir

You could try using the following as well, with a combo of VSTACK()+TAKE()+BYCOL()/MMULT() as well:


=VSTACK(
    TAKE(A1:G16, 6),
    HSTACK(
        6,
        "Others",
        BYCOL(
            DROP(A1:G16, 6, 2),
            LAMBDA(x, SUM(x))
        )
    )
)


Or, Using MMULT()
=VSTACK(
    TAKE(A1:G16, 6),
    HSTACK(
        6,
        "Others",
        MMULT(
            SEQUENCE(
                ,
                ROWS(A1:G16) -
                    6
            ) ^ 0,
            DROP(A1:G16, 6, 2)
        )
    )
)


Or, Suggested to use Structured References that is Tables which is much more better option that the following, however, a formula alternative, which takes the Column A as base and use it as a reference for the lastRow. But my money is on Tables, I will never go for the following, it is only an alternative.
=LET(
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),
     _Data, A1:INDEX(A:G, _LastRow, ),
     VSTACK(TAKE(_Data,6), HSTACK(6, "Others", BYCOL(DROP(_Data,6,2), LAMBDA(x,SUM(x))))))



Tables do not work with spill ranges. I will try your second formula as the solution needs to be dynamic.

@MarkS. Sir Ike ma'am has asked you to convert the source range into Structured References i.e. into Tables, then you can use it within the formulas. I will show you that it works.

For your formula, the issue I'm encountering is the section A1:Index(A:G. How can I write this is the data can expand or collapse before/after column G? The number of columns and rows are not fixed, which is why the solution needs to be dynamic.

@MarkS. Sir, that is also possible, but it only makes things more complicated, i will comment below

@MarkS. Sir, you can use this logic. =LET(_LastRow,MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")), _LastCol,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(1:1)/(1:1<>""),1),TAKE(A1:INDEX(A:AK,_LastRow,),,_LastCol)) so here i have taken till AK Column the pivot can expand, but you can make it as far you want, the rest remains same

@MarkS. Sir, this will be your final formula, =LET(_LastRow,MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),_LastCol,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(1:1)/(1:1<>""),1),_Data, TAKE(A1:INDEX(A:AX,_LastRow,),,_LastCol),VSTACK(TAKE(_Data,6), HSTACK(6, "Others",BYCOL(DROP(_Data,6,2),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))))) kindly try and let me know this should work!

This formula worked. Still a few things I need to adjust to have it fit my specific need, but thats on me. One final question: How can I take the total by column dynamically? Previously I was using =bycol( [spill]#, lambda( bc, sum(bc) ) ) However this formula looks at my dimensions such as my IDS, names, and headers.

@MarkS. Sir, I think, I have already shown that, you need to exclude the rest by using DROP()

Maybe I'm unclear. This is creating a table for the top x and grouping all others into "Others"; however the grand total must match the data source, so I need to grab a total by column. However, my formula can't do this because the range now includes the first 2 dimensions (Rank & Name) and headers. NVM got the formula bycol(drop( [spill]#,1,2), lambda(x,sum(x) ))

So , you need total row right? =LET(_LastRow,MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),_LastCol,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(1:1)/(1:1<>""),1),_Data, TAKE(A1:INDEX(A:AX,_LastRow,),,_LastCol), _Output, VSTACK(TAKE(_Data,6), HSTACK(6, "Others",BYCOL(DROP(_Data,6,2),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x))))),VSTACK(_Output, HSTACK("","Total",BYCOL(DROP(_Output,1,2), LAMBDA(y,SUM(y)))))) its same thing drop and use bycol, please try

Awesome, I was able to accomplish this with my own formula, but yours worked as well. I'll use yours.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Please try this (_data refers to the cell with data generated):
=LET(
_data,[cell containing the spill formula],
_data_below_top_5,DROP(_data#,6,2),
_others_row, HSTACK("","Others",BYCOL(DROP(_data#,6,2),LAMBDA(_col,SUM(_col)))),
_table_before_adding_total,VSTACK(TAKE(_data#,6),_others_row),
_totals_row,HSTACK("","Total",BYCOL(DROP(_table_before_adding_total,1,2),LAMBDA(_col,SUM(_col)))),
_empty_row,MAKEARRAY(1,COLUMNS(_data#),LAMBDA(a,b,"")),
VSTACK(_table_before_adding_total,_empty_row,_totals_row)
)

BTW, BYCOL(array,SUM) though works under Windows, does not work under Mac Excel (Microsoft 365).

What is the difference between your core formula and my formula?

Sir, you're right, there isn't much of a difference. Since the requirement was to work with a spill range, and yours wasn't taking it into account, I didn't read rest of it. Pardon me.
